# Dice Program C#. net using arrays

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I need some help with my program I built the simple dice program to show frequencies of the sum of two dice for 100 rolls. The program will read the file.

Now what i need is  to declare an array that represents the possible results of throws of two dice,For each entry in the file, increment the element of the array corresponding to that result.Last, display the frequency count for that simulation. I do not know how to use an array in my program and need help trying to implement it into my program.

```
namespace Dice_Program
{
    public partial class RollDice : Form
    {
       private int Dice1;
       private int Dice2;
       private int SUM;
       const int Roll_MAX = 100;

       private void btn_roll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           Random rand = new Random();
           for (int lineNum = 1; lineNum <= Roll_MAX; lineNum++)
           {
               Dice1 = rand.Next(6) + 1;
               Dice2 = rand.Next(6) + 1;
               SUM = Dice1 + Dice2;
               lstboxtotal.Items.Add(" On roll. "  + lineNum +  " You rolled a, "  + Dice1 + " and a "  + Dice2 +  " for a sum of " + SUM);
           }
       }

        private void btnwrite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    // Create a StreamWriter object 
            StreamWriter rollLog; 
            rollLog = File.CreateText ("Roll Results.txt"); // Creating the file

            for (int count = 0; count <lstboxtotal.Items.Count; count++)
            {
                rollLog.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(lstboxtotal.Items[count]));
            }
            rollLog.Close(); // close file after creation 
            MessageBox.Show ("Your results have been successfully Saved to file.");
        } // only first line is written 100 times

        private void btnread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (StreamReader rollLog = new StreamReader("Roll Results.txt"))
            {
                while (rollLog.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    lstboxtotal.Items.Add(rollLog.ReadLine());
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this have to be an array (homework?) or can you just use a `List<T>`?

Comment: Please search the web for "C# arrays" and follow a tutorial or two. We aren't going to do your homework.

Comment: A possible solution would also be the usage of dictionaries (if containskey is false then set to 1 else mydictionary[rollresult]++)

so is there any special reason it has to be an array?

Comment: @Sayse if you edit, please also give it a more meaningful title, without the "C#, .NET" tags.

Comment: @CodeCaster - Agreed, I missed that out after writing in an edit summary and didn't see it as a valid edit to do it on its own.

Comment: Please declare `Random rand = new Random();` outside of the method. Why? Just click fast enough and it won't be random any more

Answer (score 1):

I'm having slight trouble understanding your english. But i think you want somthing like this.

(*Note this is kinda psudo code, and wont compile straight away, butim not going todo your homework)

```
int[] Rolls = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; // 1 dice = 6 possible rolls 1- 6


void RollDice() {
    int randomRoll = GetRandomDiceRoll(); //assume this returns 1-6 for the roll

    //We use randomRoll-1 becuase the array is zero-indexed E.g. 0-5
    Rolls[randomRoll-1]++;

    //This increments the value and if the roll was 3 for instance your array will look like
    // { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 }

}
```

Comment: Yes, but OP wants the frequency of the sum of *two* dice. So `Rolls` should have `11` items (from `2` to `12`; `1` isn't possible with two dice). And then `int randomRoll = GetRandomDiceRoll() + GetRandomDiceRoll();`. The rest should be the same.

Comment: Like i said, im not doing OP's Homework. he wanted to know how to use arrays. So i gave him an example of how to implment it on a single dice. Now he can expand it onto two dice as you suggest.